# const function, but I could "modify" the class

Tags: c++, constants

I have a function in a class with `const` key word:

```
bool Machiavelli::IsStraight(std::vector<Card>& cards) const{}
```

Machiavelli is class that have other classes inside, like Card and Table:

```
class Table{
    private:
            std::map<int, std::vector<Card> > table;
    ....
};
```

The `vector` in the function is a vector of `table`. The function check if the cards assemble a straight.

Now, in the function I change the value of a data of Card function:

```
cards[i].SetIntValue(14);
```

where `SetIntValue` is a function in Card class.

Reading some question, I read:

> `const` after a function declaration means that the function is not allowed to change any class members (except ones that are marked mutable).

The function doesn't know that the argument is in Machiavelli, so I can change a class member: `table`. Where my reasoning fails?

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A method declared as `const` cannot modify members, as long as it is trying to modify them through the [implicit `this` pointer of the method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this).

Consider the following class:

```
struct foo
{
    void bar(int *i) const {
        *i = 0;
        _m = 0;
    }

    int j;
    int _m;
};
```

Suppose we call

```
foo f;
f.bar(&f.j);
```

Then the line

```
        *i = 0;
```

is fine. Even though it is actually modifying `j`, it is not doing it through `this`. However,

```
        _m = 0;
```

really means

```
        this->_m = 0;
```

and so it won't build - the `const` of the function means it cannot modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Because your `const` function is not changing a class member.

It is changing the vector that's passed as a parameter to the function.

The fact that whatever is calling the function is passing a vector that happens to be a member of the same class is a completely different issue.

Answer (score 1):

> `const` after a function declaration means that the function is not allowed to change any class members (except ones that are marked mutable).

This is not entirely right. A small but important correction is needed.

> `const` after a function declaration means that the function is not allowed to change any *data* **via** its class member **variables** (except **via** ones that are marked mutable).

Note that a variable is not data, it's a *name* for data.

Since `cards` is not a class member variable, it is possible to change data via `cards`, even if it's the same data that sits in the member variable `table`.